# pandas read xlsx - unexpected char

Tags: python, excel, pandas

i am trying to read an Excel xlsx:

```
irp = pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Downloads\\FILENAME.xlsx',sheet_name='Budgets')
```

the code is ok. changing the source makes it work. but somehow my excel is broken.

i have already changed the engine='openpyxl' and the encoding of the import, but still get this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\xlrd\xlsx.py",
> line 661, in do_row
> lv = letter_value[c] KeyError: 'a'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\Reports\COMP\01_getBudgetsFromFile.py",
> line 142, in 
> irp = pd.read_excel('C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\FILENAME.xlsx',sheet_name='Budgets')
> File
> "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel_base.py",
> line 304, in read_excel
> io = ExcelFile(io, engine=engine)   File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel_base.py",
> line 824, in **init**
> self._reader = self.*enginesengine   File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel_xlrd.py",
> line 21, in **init**
> super().**init**(filepath_or_buffer)   File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel_base.py",
> line 353, in **init**
> self.book = self.load_workbook(filepath_or_buffer)   File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel_xlrd.py",
> line 36, in load_workbook
> return open_workbook(filepath_or_buffer)   File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\xlrd_*init**.py",
> line 138, in open_workbook
> ragged_rows=ragged_rows,   File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\xlrd\xlsx.py",
> line 841, in open_workbook_2007_xml
> x12sheet.process_stream(zflo, heading)   File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\xlrd\xlsx.py",
> line 550, in own_process_stream
> self_do_row(elem)   File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\xlrd\xlsx.py",
> line 669, in do_row
> raise Exception('Unexpected character %r in cell name %r' % (c, cell_name)) Exception: Unexpected character 'a' in cell name 'a1'

any idea?

thanks

//UPDATE

using openpyxl I get this error:

here is the error I get with openpyxl:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\base.py", line 55, in _convert
    value = expected_type(value)
TypeError: Fill() takes no arguments

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\eclipse-workspace\Reports\COMP\01_getBudgetsFromFile.py", line 147, in <module>
    irp = pd.read_excel('C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Downloads\\FILENAME.xlsx',sheet_name='Budgets', engine="openpyxl") 
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 304, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(io, engine=engine)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 824, in __init__
    self._reader = self._engines[engine](self._io)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_openpyxl.py", line 485, in __init__
    super().__init__(filepath_or_buffer)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 353, in __init__
    self.book = self.load_workbook(filepath_or_buffer)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_openpyxl.py", line 497, in load_workbook
    filepath_or_buffer, read_only=True, data_only=True, keep_links=False
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 315, in load_workbook
    reader.read()
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 279, in read
    apply_stylesheet(self.archive, self.wb)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\styles\stylesheet.py", line 192, in apply_stylesheet
    stylesheet = Stylesheet.from_tree(node)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\styles\stylesheet.py", line 102, in from_tree
    return super(Stylesheet, cls).from_tree(node)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\serialisable.py", line 103, in from_tree
    return cls(**attrib)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\styles\stylesheet.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.fills = fills
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\sequence.py", line 26, in __set__
    seq = [_convert(self.expected_type, value) for value in seq]
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\sequence.py", line 26, in <listcomp>
    seq = [_convert(self.expected_type, value) for value in seq]
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\base.py", line 57, in _convert
    raise TypeError('expected ' + str(expected_type))
TypeError: expected <class 'openpyxl.styles.fills.Fill'>
```

Comment: Does the following command work? `df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Downloads\\FILENAME.xlsx', sheet_name='Budgets', encoding='utf8')`

Comment: nope. same error! thx

Comment: when I open the file and press save. my original code works. encoding issue? problem is, that the files are coming automatically on my server and need to be processed without me touching them :D

Comment: from reading the error it seems it can't parse the cell name as it is  getting a lowercase 'a' in the name where I guess it expects an uppercase. I wanted to check the code but the error you have is using the package `xlrd` that specifically states it doesn't support  `.xlsx` files [see doc](https://xlrd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). What error do you get when using `openpyxl`?

Comment: funnily there is no "a" in the title. see update above for error with openpyxl

Comment: the 'a' in the error refers to the cell name itself, not its value. As you can see in the error, it refers to cell 'a1'. Anyway that's not the core issue. Based on the openpyxl error, this is indeed a format issue. Are you able to share a problematic file without sensitive data? Since the issue disapear if you save the file, it may be complicated to get a curated one.

Comment: I hope I did not fix the encoding now by copying the file :) https://dorland.box.com/s/dy5j0k2nrzyzpglbtc1jkxi5ln0yqbzg thanks!

Comment: So I was able to open it by silencing the error directly in `openpyxl` source code :D. This doesn't look like a good fix though. My understanding is that there is one cell in the file for which the style info has no `fill` parameters and `openpyxl` doesn't like it.

Comment: There is a similar issue reported [here](https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/issues/1285) in the repo and the answer seems to be the source of Excel file doesn't comply with the standard :s. Can you somehow change the source format to CSV, ODS or something else?

Comment: unfortunalty I cannot change It :(

Answer (score 1):

Since you cannot change the source, you can try the below fix. Change can be done in the source code of your virtual environment or you can clone/fork the repo of openpyxl make the modif in your local repo and install this modified package.

It is strongly advised to have a specific virtual environment for this since you would be using a modified version of a package.

Modify the file `openpyxl/descriptorsbase.py` (in you case it is here `"C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\descriptors\base.py"`) to replace the `class Typed` with the below. I have just replaced the raising error by a non blocking print.

**IMPORTANT:** This is a hack, not a proper solve. There may be a way to fix the xlsx file without opening it with pandas. But, as far as I can see, this is an easy way out for now.

```py
class Typed(Descriptor):
    """Values must of a particular type"""

    expected_type = type(None)
    allow_none = False
    nested = False

    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super(Typed, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
        self.__doc__ = "Values must be of type {0}".format(self.expected_type)

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if not isinstance(value, self.expected_type):
            if (not self.allow_none
                or (self.allow_none and value is not None)):
                """ Below 2 lines are my modif"""
                print('Ignored error: expected ' + str(self.expected_type) + ' but got' + str(value))
                # raise TypeError('expected ' + str(self.expected_type))
        super(Typed, self).__set__(instance, value)

    def __repr__(self):
        return  self.__doc__


def _convert(expected_type, value):
    """
    Check value is of or can be converted to expected type.
    """
    if not isinstance(value, expected_type):
        try:
            value = expected_type(value)
        except:   
            """ Below 2 lines are my modif"""
            print('Ignored error: expected ' + str(expected_type) + ' but got' + str(value))
            # raise TypeError('expected ' + str(expected_type))
    return value
```

**EDIT - root cause**: I continued to dig and found out where the issue is. `xlsx` files are `zip` archives of `xml` files. By comparing the non-working version and the working version after saving on my system and looking for something around the `fill` settings based on the error, I found the culprit.
In the file `styles.xml`, there is one empty style that is an empty tag `<fill />`, in the correct version, it is replaced by `<fill><patternFill patternType="none"/></fill>`. Based on that, you can solve it by:

- Unzip the `xlsx` file
- replace the problematic string in `styles.xml`
- Zip back the `xlsx` file

Is it better or more secure than the above? Probably not... but there may be a way to get that empty tag managed by Openpyxl as a bugfix.

In cas your interested, here is the code:

```py
import shutil, os, zipfile
zip_filename = "PROC_Budgets.xlsx"
unzip_folder = "unzipped_files"
# Open the zip file and extract the XML file to the "unzip_folder"
with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_filename) as zip_file:
    zip_file.extractall(unzip_folder)

# Open the problematic xml file
with open(os.path.join(unzip_folder, "xl/styles.xml"), "r") as f:
    data = f.read()
# replace the empty tag
corrected = data.replace("<fill />", '<fill><patternFill patternType="none"/></fill>')
# overwrite the xml file
with open(os.path.join(unzip_folder, "xl/styles.xml"), "w") as f:
    f.write(corrected)

zip_filename_modified = "PROC_Budgets - modified.xlsx"
dir_name = ""
shutil.make_archive(zip_filename_modified[:-5], 'zip', dir_name)
os.rename(zip_filename_modified[:-5]+'.zip', zip_filename_modified)
```

And after all that, the `pd.read_excel()` should work :D